# Create Control Track for BWAV Audio Description

Tags: track, control

One of the client in UK is asking for BWAV AD file with control Track. How to Create Control Track for BWAV Audio Description and export as .wav file

Comment: Hello. I have never heard of BWF control track. Is your client asking for ADM metadata ? As in https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BS.2076/en ?

Answer (score 0):

- https://www.w3.org/2013/10/tv-workshop/papers/webtv4_submission_4.pdf
- https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/tech/tech3285s5.pdf

you require a tool that will add the AXML RIFF chunk to your BWF.

- https://mediaarea.net/BWFMetaEdit/Download